# Route.go() on account creation doesn't work (METEOR)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

I have a hook on my webapp that redirects the user to the edit profile page on their first login/registration.

It looks a bit like this:

Accounts.onCreateUser (options, user) ->
  if options.profile

```
options.profile.aboutMe = null
options.profile.email = null
options.instrumentsPlayed = null
options.instrumentsPlayedTemporary = null

Router.go('edit_form')
```

user

So it adds a few fields to the profile page, and supposedly the Router.go line should redirect the user to the edit_form page. I have tried the code without the Router.go line and it works properly. I am running this in a server file. When I try to log/register in with the Router.go line present, it gives me an "internal server error" and doesn't log in. When I run it without, it runs everything properly but obviously does not redirect. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try smth like this, on client:

```
Template.signup.events "submit #signup": (e, t) ->
 Meteor.call "registerUser", email, password, profile, (err, result) ->
   if err
     throwError err.reason
     console.log err
   else
     Router.go "/edit_form"
```

`Accounts.onCreateUser (options, user)` works only on the server, but you want redirect client. `registerUser` it's my Meteor method, where I call `Accounts.onCreateUser (options, user)`

Comment: I'm using the accounts-facebook login package, so the button forlogin and registration is the same. I only want it to redirect once a new user was added to the database though... Can I do something like this instead? Set a session variable, on the server side, when a new account is created, change its value. Every time the value is changed (meaning the first time someone logs in), redirect the user to the edit profile page (the session variable is callable in both server and client, correct?)

Comment: No, Session exists only on client. You can add some option to profile, when you create user, for example, `profile.firstLogin = true;` When in function `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` in callback function, if result have no errors, redirect to path `/edit_form`. And you have to change this option `profile.firstLogin` when user will finish editing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to run your redirects on the client, not on the server.

You *could* use a callback on the registration method, so that when a user has created an account she will be redirected. But most likely you *never* want a logged in user to visit the register or sign in pages. To handle that you can use Meteors reactivity. On the registration page you can use hooks to redirect the user if she is logged in.

```
this.route('register', {
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if (Meteor.userId())
      this.redirect('myRouteForLoggedInUsers')
  }
});
```

Now, when a user is registering she is on the `register` route but she is not logged in, so she wont be redirected. As soon as the registration process is complete she will still be on the `register` route but she will be logged in. Because of Meteors reactivity the `onBeforeAction` function will rerun (since the result of `Meteor.userId()` has changed) and thus she will be redirected.

You can use this on the sign in page too, so anyone who is logged in will be redirected instead of seeing the sign in page.